# What is the difference between "blatant" and "flagrant"

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, adjectives, word-difference

I'm English learner in Korea.

In Korean, "blatant" and "flagrant" has no difference.

However, the Word Smart 6th edition told me, don't confuse them.

But I can't get the difference between them.

Can you explain it with some examples?

Comment: I assume when you say *In Korean, "blatant" and "flagrant" has no difference* you just mean that when you read Korean definitions of those two English words in a (Korean) learner's dictionary, you can't tell the difference. Try comparing the two definitions in an *English* dictionary, and then tell us what you don't understand.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually, I'm using Word Smart in English version and Collins English Dictionary. I read and read them, but I can't understand the difference. So my final choice was the Eng-Kor dictionary, but I was confused more..

Comment: Haha - having looked at the two definitions in Collins, I can see your problem! The two words are *very* close in "meaning", obviously, but there's not much in Collins to help you see the potential slight difference in nuance. If @James's answer doesn't cover *everything*, you might be interested in this...

Comment: ...[*Both mean **offensively conspicuous** or **conspicuously offensive**. Offensively conspicuous is usually associated with **blatant,** while conspicuously offensive is associated with **flagrant,** but these two meanings tend to overlap. Combine this with the words’ similarity in sound, and the result is that most English speakers treat them as interchangeable.*](http://grammarist.com/usage/blatant-flagrant/)

Comment: Just a couple more points. If you have a similar problem with some other pair of English words in future, check the ***etymology***. That'll often give you clues as to possible *current* usage differences. Also check ***relative prevalence*** using Google Books, NGrams, or similar - even if two words really *are* true synonyms (extremely uncommon), it makes a big difference if one is used far more often than the other.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for your tips. Your answer is so helpful that I can refer your answers later, even now.

Comment: Thinking about the fact that our Help pages list *practical problems you encounter or face while learning English* as valid subjects to ask about, I reckon we could do with one along the lines of *What different approaches are useful when trying to figure out the difference between two English words that seem (to me, as a learner) to mean the same thing?* If you, for example, were to ask such a question I'd happily upvote it. And anyone who wanted could copy anything I wrote above and incorporate it into an answer (ideally a ***much-extended answer*** with lots more useful tips / insights! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course "blatant" and "flagrant" are not the same in Korean, because they are not Korean words!  What you mean is "my dictionary translates both to the same Korean word".

This is because they do have very similar and overlapping meanings in English, and there are lots of times when you could use either.

*Blatant* means "obvious", (originally it meant "making a loud noise). If something is so obvious that it is annoying you can call it blatant.

*Flagrant* means offensive or outrageous. (It comes from a word meaning "on fire") If something is so offensive that it obvious you can call it "flagrant"

In very many situations you could use either.

Some examples from football:

> He punched the football away with his hand, that was a blatant handball. Why didn't the referee see it??
>
> That was a sliding tackle with both feet, and took the player out. It was a flagrant foul.  It should have been a red card!

Source http://grammarist.com/usage/blatant-flagrant/ Has more examples

Comment: Yes. Flagrant is usually the best choice when emphasising negative intentions behind an obvious act, while blatant is better when emphasising the obvious nature of a negative act.

Comment: Interestingly, the phrase *blatantly flagrant* makes sense to me; however, *flagrantly blatant* does not.

Comment: Thanks for your answers !! I understand them thoroughly!